# QML TreeView collapse section when click different section

Tags: qt, qml, treeview, accordion

I have a QML TreeView which expands / collapses branches upon click (builtin to treeview).  However, when I expand one branch, I want other branches at the same depth to collapse.  I've gotten as far as the code below which collapses ALL branches when an item is clicked.

How can I collapse ONLY branches which are NOT on the path from root index to the clicked index?  (Either in C++ or JS)?  So that it behaves like an accordion

In my TreeView:

```
    onClicked: {
        console.log(index)
        for(var i=0; i < treemodel.rowCount(); i++) {
            var nextIndex = treemodel.index(i,0)
            if(mytreeview.isExpanded(nextIndex)) {
                mytreeview.collapse(nextIndex)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify if this is the `TreeView` from QQC1 or the one for QQC2 from the Qt MarketPlace?

Comment: QML TreeView is part of QtQuick.Controls 1.4  (I don't think there is a TreeView in QQC2)

Comment: There is in the marketplace: https://marketplace.qt.io/products/treeview